# Display message if nothing returned from Query

Tags: php, mysql, database

How do I display a message if nothing is returned from my query?
I tried this:

```
while($info2 = mysql_fetch_assoc( $data2 )) 
{
    // la la la lots of code here
}
else
{
    echo "Nothing Returned"; 
}
```

Only to get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE

Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: Please read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php). There is no `while`/`else` syntax in any programming language. Questions such as this are just embarrassing.

Comment: I found this through a google search on a MySQL forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
 if(mysql_num_rows($data2) > 0){
    //while loop goes here 
 } else {
    //echo message
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysql_num_rows` to check number of rows returned by query

```
if(mysql_num_rows($data2) > 0)
{
   while($info2 = mysql_fetch_assoc( $data2 )) 
  {
     ///la la la lot's of code here
  }
}
 else
{
echo "Nothing Returned"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple PHP function:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($data2) != 0)
{
    // your while
}
else
{
    // if nothing
}
```

This function just count how many rows are returned.

Comment: Think you've got you're comments reversed ... :-)

Comment: You are showing that the while loop goes where `num_rows == 0` when, in fact, the error message should go where the `num_rows == 0` ...

Answer (score 1):

else statement can only follow after an if statement. you should also check [affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)